# Unable to Activate Windows EC2 instance via KMS

Tags: amazon-ec2, kms

I have an EC2 Instance Windows Server Datacenter 2008, and I'm getting an "Unable to Activate Windows" message. Even after following through the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/common-messages.html#activate-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, the *Registered KMS Machine name* wasn't set. When I ran:

```
slmgr /dlv
```

There was no "Key Management Service client information" section.

The fix then, was to run the following to manually set a KMS:

```
slmgr /skms 169.254.169.250:1688
```

After which, you can activate windows again with the following:

```
slmgr /ato
```

Comment: Further info - this is documented in some more detail at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/common-messages.html#activate-windows  and https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/windows-activation-fails/

Comment: @Criggie yeah, I think the documentation has improved in the past 6 years and 7 months. ;)